# No network connection using git (bitbucket)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using git bash to clone a repository on bitbucket.

```
git clone https://my-user-name@bitbucket.org/repo-name
```

I get an error message

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://my-user-name@bitbucket.org/my-user-name/repo-name':
Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org
```

Also I cannot ping. My guess is that git bash cannot access the network
But my command prompt (cmd.exe) allows for ping and other network commands
When I ping in the git terminal window:

```
ping 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
```

But this happens:

```
ping google.com
Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again
.
```

How do I fix this?

I am on a network without proxy, disabling firewall does not help

Comment: It will be easier for people to help you if you show the exact command you run, and the exact output. Also, what is "git bash"?

Comment: thank you for the input, the tutorial on bitbucket.org is calling the terminal window "Git Bash".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo and behold the firewall was blocking the connection. I only discovered this by uninstalling the firewall. I did not think this would be the case as I had disabled the firewall, sandbox, and HIPS. Somehow the software was still blocking network access on git.